# Oracle SQL - a hint clause and a table alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been just transferred to the new job site and given a set of sqls which are in operation. There are several sqls which are written like [A] below. What looks weird to me is that the alias of the table is the same as the table name itself. Allow me to ask you two questions about [A].

```
[A] select /*+ INDEX(TableA IDX01) */ from TableA TableA 
[B] select /*+ INDEX(a IDX01) */ from TableA a 
[C] select /*+ INDEX(TableA IDX01) */ from TableA a
```

Q1. Is hint clause in [A] valid? I know that hint clause in [C] is invalid because the table name is used instead of the alias in the hint clause, though that in [B] is valid.

Q2. Is there any advantage to give a table the same alias as its name?

Thanks in advance for your generous support for an oracle beginner working alone at the new environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first hint appears to be syntactically valid (though presumably you can test that yourself) assuming that `IDX01` is an index that exists on `TableA` and that it is possible for the query to use that index.  I'm not a fan of having this sort of hint in production code since it generally implies that you're trying to cover up an underlying problem with statistics but it appears to be valid.

There is nothing wrong with using an alias that matches the table name.  It's possible that someone added that alias to make the hint valid or because the query originally didn't have an alias and some of the columns in the `select` list or `where` clause were using the `table_name.column_name` syntax.  Of course, there are other possibilities that we could speculate about.  Someone in your organization may know more of the history or source control might show the evolution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! And what is more, It seems to be a perfect answer.  I'll need more and more experiences to have an excellent speculation like yours. Now I'm ignorant of how to find if a hint is actually used, as long as the plan shows that the index is used. I'll try to find the way. Thank you very much once again!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to respond only to your second question. It is absolutely OK to provide an alias with the same name as the table, and absolutely unnecessary to do so. It adds no clarity, and you can still use the `table_name.column_name` syntax without the alias.

Comment: Brian, Thanks very much for your comment and sorry for the late reply! I think the unnecessary, same-name aliases were left in the way that Justin guessed, though I couldn't find anyone who knows the actual history. Anyway, thanks so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Since we are forcing the database to use the provided index, In order for the hints to work, you have to specify either a table alias or table name in the hint. like the below sql snippet. Otherwise the specified index index in the hint won't be picked up.

```
select /*+ INDEX(a IDX01) */ from TableA a
```

or

```
select /*+ INDEX(TableA IDX01) */ from TableA TableA
```